# How to make formatting of information to print (in a real printer) easier?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, gdi+

So i'm going crazy here because i had an invoice like this (as an example):

[image]

I finally got the coordinates of each thing i needed to print right, after like 30 or more attempts and adjusting the x and y coordinate of each thing every single time, plus the adjustment i had to do for the specific printer's way of printing.

Isn't there an easier way to do that besides a lot of trial and error?

all i did to print was adjust the x and y of this one line of code(it was a nightmare):

```
graphic.DrawString("string to print", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), x, y);
```

Comment: You're filling a pre-printed form... There might be report generators that will do some of the work for you but the measuring and trial-and-error will stay. This is so thight you'll need to watch the humidity of the stored paper.

Comment: Lots of practice ;-)  Seriously: There are ways to scan in an attempted printout and measure the offsets so you need only 1 or 2 tries but setting that up would amount to even more trial and error. With practice comes patience.. Of course, after getting the measurements right, you ought to find out only ONE offset point, all others should follow! On a minor nore: Instead of `new SolidBrush(Color.Black)` you can simply write `Brushes.Black`.

Comment: Ohh, will do that haha, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried scanning it in and displaying it in a way that as you click you capture the current coordinates and use that as a method to determine the coordinates of were you want to start printing from once off. I would recommend dumping the current report and attempting to duplicate it as a report.

Comment: I will do that from now on, i honestly didn't think about it and it does sound like it will save me a lot of time compared to being "guessing" where the coordinate would be x_x thanks!